# Visualizing case-control 2D count data in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have some count data that look like this:

```
Counts in case:
       A
       0   1   2
B  0 602 398  95
   1  69  53   8
   2   2   0   0

Counts in control:

       A
       0    1    2
B  0 1299  775   91
   1  127   41    2
   2    2    0    0
```

0, 1, and 2 are just the attributes that we are counting. For example, in the control group, 1299 person are counted both as A0 and B0, while in the case group 8 people are counted both as A2 and B1.

I am wondering what is the best way to visualize this (in R)?

Comment: There is a `plot.table` method in R; you could see something like `plot(as.table(array(c(case, control), c(dim(case), 2))))` (specifying appropriate "dimnames").

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to plot the data in bar plot. I am making up my down data in a melted format (reshape2: melt) which is 2 by 2 matrix. Your is 3 by 3 but it is the same idea.

```
data1 <- data.frame(groupa = c(0,0,1,1), groupb= c(0,1,0,1), type="case", value=1:4)
data2 <- data.frame(groupa = c(0,0,1,1), groupb= c(0,1,0,1), type="control", value=5:6)
data <- rbind(data1, data2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=type, y=value,  fill=type)) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(. ~ groupa + groupb)
```

You have a plot looks like this:

[image]

In your case, you will have 3 * 3 = 9 cells.